# Is it possible to use ScanSnap IX500 with c# / vb?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, twain, wia

I am trying to scan a document from the ScanSnap IX500 and to display it as pdf into my visual studio project. (VS2017 & W7 pro)

I didn't find any solution on the web for this. It's not possible to use TWAIN or WIA, so I'm trapped.

If someone has a way to make it works, I would be pleased :)

Comment: Doesn't Fujitsu provide an [SDK](http://www.fujitsu.com/uk/products/computing/peripheral/scanners/imaging-alliance-program/scansnap/)? Can you use the scanner from applications like Word, or using Windows tools?

Comment: is there a driver with a DLL you can call via COM?